# Difference between using blocking write and event.wait() with non-blocking write on OpenCL

Tags: gpu, opencl, blocking, nonblocking, read-write

This may end up being silly, but I stumbled into this question and I am not being able to answer it myself.

What is the practical difference between using the following two pieces of code when writing to a buffer in OpenCL?

1. Blocking write:

```cpp
queue->enqueueWriteBuffer(d_vec, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int) * vec.size(), vec.data());
```

2. Non-blocking write with event.wait():

```cpp
cl::Event event;
queue->enqueueWriteBuffer(d_vec, CL_FALSE, 0, sizeof(int) * vec.size(), vec.data(), nullptr, &event);
event.wait();
```

It seems to me that both codes would behave the same in the end. Can anyone explain the difference?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are effectively the same if that's all you're doing. However, if you're additionally enqueueing kernels or other non-blocking operations to a concurrent queue, or to other queues, then the buffer write or read can potentially run in parallel to those other operations. You can also skip waiting for the write event to complete by using the event as an input (dependency) for a subsequent enqueued task.

The blocking write is just a shortcut for when you don't need any of those abilities.

Comment: thanks for the answer! Would you know if these blocking and non-blocking writes can behave differently in Intel and NVidia? The reason I ask this is that I have a full program with some OpenCL kernels and I'm getting divergent behavior with NVidia and Intel. I've ran some tests on both and confirmed that the kernels yield the same results, which left me thinking that it could be something with the writes. If you know some references where I can read more on this it would be really helpful. (BTW when running my program on NVidia the program fails and on Intel it succeeds). Thanks again

Comment: @J.E.Chiarelli Well, Intel implementations use a unified memory architecture - device and host memory are the same physical memory - so reads and writes will not necessarily force an actual copy - it could be implemented via copy-on-write mapping, etc.

Comment: @J.E.Chiarelli it’s possible the code somehow relies on an aspect of this implementation detail difference. Are you sure all enqueued kernels, buffer reads and writes, host memory accesses, etc. correctly have their dependency events set, or use appropriate serial queues?

Comment: @J.E.Chiarelli it’s hard to make specific suggestions without seeing the code

Comment: your answers are being very helpful. I didn't know about this unified memory architecture and copy-on-write features of Intel. The code I'm working on is rather large, and I wouldn't like to waste anymore of your time, but if you are curious, you can see it [here](https://github.com/OPM/opm-simulators/tree/master/opm/simulators/linalg/bda) and my problem is with this [module](https://github.com/OPM/opm-simulators/blob/master/opm/simulators/linalg/bda/WellContributionsOCLContainer.cpp).

Comment: @JoséEduardoBueno The code there isn't exactly linear so there's nothing obviously wrong that jumps out at me. But if you're suspecting synchronisation issues, I'd try waiting for the kernel to complete after queueing in `applyStdWells`. I'd also check if the queue that's being used is concurrent or serial.

Comment: thanks a lot again! I've tried to wait the kernel in `applyStdWells` to complete and also the kernel that runs before it but still no luck for NVidia... But anyway I'll keep digging